# How to minify javascript file generated by liquid template generator

Tags: javascript, css, minify, liquid

I'm trying to optimize the shopify website and GoogleSpeed Insights recommends me to minify css and js files.

The recommended files are all generated by liquid template generator, so I can't use the popular minify tools available.

If anyone have experience in this issue, please advise me.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you ellaborate why you can not use gulp or another taskrunner for the minification? Even if the files are generated by some generator you can watch the output directory for changes and minify the generated files.

Comment: Most likely because of liquid's curly brace + percent sign delimiters ({% ...%}) which cause minifiers to throw syntax errors

Answer (score 2):

If you try to minify such file, you will see an error because of Liquid templating code. Here is a trick which can help you to minify JavaScript files containing Liquid templating code. But this involves little manual labor.

Replace all Liquid templating code with some random unique string. Remember all the replacements. You can use a file diff app to find the difference of a `.js.liquid` file and the generated `.js` file so that it will be easy to find where you need to replace. Now you can minify this modified file without any error using any JavaScript minification tool. After the minification is over, you can replace the random unique strings with their corresponding replacements.

I am optimizing a theme for a good PageSpeed Insights score. This trick helped me to minify, combine and compress many `.js.liquid` files.

Comment: Thank you @FoNko. Please upvote the answer, if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this with pagespeed, but it looks like it works html level.

In Business Catalyst I am able to do the following with liquid

```
{% assign allthedata = {{myData|json}} -%}

{{allthedata | remove: ' '}}
```

I don't know if this would affect pagespeed, but it is simple enough to try it

This removes all the spaces I have in myData.json which is generated dynamically.

Answer (score -2):

https://prepros.io/

I've been using this app for like 7 months, and I absolutely love it. It can convert and compress your files.

I'm using SASS as my CSS preprocessor, and this app helps me to keep my code clean, here's my way how I make 10 files into one file and compress it:

1. Create 10 .sass files
2. Create one more .sass file where you will import all these files into one, I call it main.sass
3. Use prepros to import all the files into one and then convert it to main.css
4. So, for debugging I leave the main.css and create another css files called main-dist.css
5. Use prepros to compress main.css to main-dist.css.

And here you go, you got 2 different css files, one compressed and one not. You can use main.css when creating the website, for debugging purposes and later, when you're done and your website works perfectly, you can use main-dist.css and have your styles compressed.

Oh, btw I don't know how to work with Grunt or Gulp, and I love this app because of it's simplicity

P.S I'm using trial version (**it's free**) and planning to buy this app as soon as I get some work to do for clients.

Comment: Do you know what .liquid is?